# Which serialization format is it?

Tags: serialization, identification

I have a binary file containing ascii strings like `{'ClassName': 'Array', 'Type': ... }`, and I'd like to identify this format. It seems the file was created using Java or C++, but I cannot find which the serialization library/format. Can anybody help with this?

Comment: on a unix/linux/bsd system you can try `file /path/to/file.ext`. What is the extension of the file? Add more information to your question. I doubt some can help without more information. It could also be C# or someone has written a custom serializer in Java, ... or ...

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer, the extension is not known, it looks like data is written by rather old in-house code, `file` command indicates just "data". What kind of other information can help?

Comment: For example: Provide a bigger part of the file. Is there a magic number that could identify the writing technology. Try to find the magic by entering `od -t x1 -c /path/to/file.ext | less` in the linux terminal. This command prints out the file content byte by byte in hex and ascii. If there is a magic number then you mostly find it  in the first four, six or eight bytes. A Java class file for instance uses `0x CA FE BA BE` for the magic number. ;-) The best way is to find the author of the inhouse app. I do not think that someone in the internet know about your companies file formats. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @PeterPaulKiefer, I know about magic numbers, but it is not the case. The file starts with the string I mentioned, followed by array  attributes (type, size etc) and binary array data, this stuff is repeated several times with slight variation. Surely if I knew the author, I'd ask him directly, I hope he/she used some standard library and it can be identified by someone. Thanks for input anyway.

Comment: I found the following link to a simulation format. Scroll down. The Intro is the same. http://cfd.mace.manchester.ac.uk/twiki/pub/Main/VictorPepin/Laminar_lid-driven_cavity.sim

Comment: It is a simulation written in Star-CCM+ by CD-adapco. Perhaps we got it :-).

Comment: Looks similar, I'll try to contact them and ask about serialization library they use. Thanks!